# Is this Barbarossa token used in a boardgame?

Tags: identify-this-game

I found a few of these Barbarossa tokens in the back garden - similar to those depicted [here](https://en.numista.com/catalogue/pieces23780.html).

> BARBAROSSA - CORSAIR KING OF ALGIERS
>   SCOURGE OF MEDITERRANEAN AS PIRATE AND ADMIRAL OF THE TURKISH FLEET FROM 1536

It's aluminium and just feels to me that it might be part of a treasure chest piece on a board game, or a tacky souvenir from a Turkish tourist trap!

Comment: From a quick search it looks like a generic souvenir.

Comment: I agree with Samthere, does not appear to be a game piece to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token you have found is not from a board game, but is rather a promotional token minted as part of a 4 coin series for Sugar Puffs in 1967.

Barbarossa is the most common of the tokens, but considering one of the tag lines was "Stash away your own pirate treasure" it makes sense a child might bury their treasure.

[image]

Comment: How on earth did you unearth that? Well done!

Comment: I recently received one of the Long John Silver tokens that was labeled as "Sugar Puffs Long John Silver", before that I thought they might have been tokens from an arcade or magazine.

Answer (score 7):

As you indicated in the question, there are existing tokens (i.e. coins, possibly as a souvenir) that bears the exact same inscription in your question.

[image: Barbarosa token heads] [image: Barbarosa token tails]

Two commenters have already indicated that the token does not appear to be part of a board game. Given the similarity to non-board game tokens and the fact that nobody has been able to identify it as part of a board game in over a year, I'm inclined to say that this is *not* a board game piece.